# Creating a new empty property to an Eloquent collection

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a collection that I cycle through and attempt to add a new property `suffix` with an empty values.

```
    $results = Models\EloTable
        ::hydrate((array) $query)
        ->load(
            'extraction',
            'reference'
        );

    foreach ($results as $result) {
        foreach ($result->data->authors as $author) {
            $author->suffix = '';
        }
    }
```

Currently, every `$author` has two properties,

```
{
    lastName: "Lastname",
    firstName: "Firstname"
}
```

If I `dd($author);` after the first iteration, I will get

```
{
    lastName: "Lastname",
    firstName: "Firstname",
    suffix: ""
}
```

But if I `dd($results);` after the two `foreach` loops, it will not persist the addition of the empty `suffix` properties.

How can I change the collection to persist the `suffix` property?

Comment: Can you post the `EloTable` Model code?

Answer (score 0):

You can append an attribute to a model like this:

Model:

```
protected $appends = ['suffix'];

public function getSuffixAttribute()
{
    return null;  
}
```

Documentation:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-mutators

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-serialization#appending-values-to-json

Comment: The problem with appends is that the suffix will be added to the main level of each document as a property. I don't want it to be `$result->suffix`, I want it to be `$result->data->authors->SUFFIX HERE`, where the first and last names are. Any way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't load `data` and `data.authors` in your original `$results` then calling `$results->data->authors` or something similar later down the line will re-query the database, pulling a fresh copy of `authors` that hasn't been modified.

Just change `$results` to :

```
$results = Models\EloTable
        ::hydrate((array) $query)
        ->load(
            'extraction',
            'reference',
            'data',
            'data.authors',
        );
```